# Is there a better way to use Lambda with groups of N?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the method `Process(IEnumerable<Record> records)` which can take UP TO but NO MORE THAN 3 records at a time. I have hundreds of records, so I need to pass in groups. I do this:

```
var _Records = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i += 3)
{
    var _ShortList = _Records.Skip(i).Take(3);
    if (!_ShortList.Any())
        break;
    Process(_ShortList);
}
// TODO: finish
```

It works, but... is there a better way?

Comment: There is always a better way than `break` inside of a loop...

Comment: You can change your `for` for a `while` with your breaking condition inside. It will be shorter and cleaner.

Comment: @Mualig. The obvious answer... +1

Comment: This is very inefficient - you have 2 calls to `Skip` (and `Take`) per every iteration of the loop. One in `Any` and one in `Process` (due to the deferred execution). Since each `Skip` iterates over roughly N/2 elements on average, the whole thing is O(N^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkSize)
{
    return source
        .Select((value, i) => new { Index = i, Value = value })
        .GroupBy(item => item.Index % chunkSize)
        .Select(chunk => chunk.Select(item => item.Value));
}
```

It splits a source collection of items into several chunks with given size.
So your code will look next:

```
foreach (var chunk in Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Split(3))
{
    Process(chunk);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s `Batch`

```
var result=Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Batch(3);
```

or

```
var arrayOfArrays = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Batch(3).Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

And here is the [source](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) if you want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another LINQ-y way to do it:

```
var batchSize = 3;
Enumerable.Range(0, (_Records.Length - 1)/batchSize + 1)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(i => Process(_Records.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize)));
```

Comment: Wow, you really simplified it. ;)

Comment: If you're not into the whole, you know, clarity thing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need "pagination" multiple times in your solution, you may consider using an extension method.

Hacked one together in LINQPad, it will do the trick.

```
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Paginate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int pageSize) {
        T[] buffer = new T[pageSize];
        int index = 0;

        foreach (var item in source) {
            buffer[index++] = item;

            if (index >= pageSize) {
                yield return buffer.Take(pageSize);
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        if (index > 0) {
            yield return buffer.Take(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, it pre-fills a buffer of size `pageSize` and yields it just when it's full. If there are `< pageSize` elements left, we yield them as well. So,

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Paginate(3).Dump(); // Dump is a LINQPad extension
```

will yield

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _Records = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).ToArray();

int index = 0;
foreach (var group in _Records.GroupBy(element => index++ / 3))
    Process(group);
```

---

NOTE: The code above is short and relatively efficient, but is still not as efficient as it can be (it will essentially build a hashtable behind the scenes). A slightly more cumbersome, but faster way would be:

```
var _Records = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).ToArray();

var buff = new int[3];
int index = 0;

foreach (var element in _Records) {
    if (index == buff.Length) {
        Process(buff);
        index = 0;
    }
    buff[index++] = element;
}

if (index > 0)
    Process(buff.Take(index));
```

Or, pack it to a more reusable form:

```
public static class EnumerableEx {

    public static void Paginate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int page_size, Action<IEnumerable<T>> process_page) {

        var buff = new T[3];
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var element in elements) {
            if (index == buff.Length) {
                process_page(buff);
                index = 0;
            }
            buff[index++] = element;
        }

        if (index > 0)
            process_page(buff.Take(index));

    }

}

// ...

var _Records = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).ToArray();
_Records.Paginate(3, Process);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own extension method:

```
static class Extensions {

  public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ToBlocks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int blockSize) {
    var count = 0;
    T[] block = null;
    foreach (var item in source) {
      if (block == null)
        block = new T[blockSize];
      block[count++] = item;
      if (count == blockSize) {
        yield return block;
        block = null;
        count = 0;
      }
    }
    if (count > 0)
      yield return block.Take(count);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void ChunkProcess<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int size, Action<IEnumerable<T>> action)
{
    var chunk = source.Take(size);

    while (chunk.Any())
    {
        action(chunk);

        source = source.Skip(size);
        chunk = source.Take(size);
    }
}
```

and your code would be

```
ChunkProcess(_Records, 3, Process);
```

Answer (score 0):

This extension method is working properly.

```
public static class EnumerableExtentions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int   size)
    {
        return
            items.Select((member, index) => new { Index = index, Value = member })
                .GroupBy(item => (int)item.Index / size)
                .Select(chunk => chunk.Select(item => item.Value));
    }
}
```